# Sencha Touch 2 store doesn't load within floating panel

Tags: sencha-touch-2, store

I'm trying to load a list within a floating panel.  It works with static values but it doesn't load using a json file.

If I tried this and it works:

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
left: 0,
padding: 10,
width: 300,
height: 300,
modal: true,
hideOnMaskTap: true,
layout: 'fit',
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'list',
        scrollable: true,
        ui: 'round',
        height: '100%',
        store: {
            fields: ['name'],
            data: [
                {name: 'Cowper'},
                {name: 'Everett'},
                {name: 'University'},
                {name: 'Forest'}
            ]
        },
        itemTpl: '{name}'
    }
]
});
```

But when I try to call a Json file, it doesn't work.  This is the panel:

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
left: 0,
padding: 10,
width: 300,
height: 300,
modal: true,
hideOnMaskTap: true,
layout: 'fit',
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'list',
        scrollable: true,
        ui: 'round',
        height: '100%',
        store: 'storeCardStatus',
        itemTpl: '{Card_Status}'
    }
]
});
```

This is the store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.storeCardStatus',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
config: {
    model: 'MyApp.model.modelCardStatus',
    autoLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'card_status.json',
        reader: 'json'
    }
}
});
```

This is the model:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.modelCardStatus', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config: {
    fields: [
        {name: 'Card_Status', type: 'string'}
    ]
}
});
```

This is the Json file:

```
[
{"Card_Status": "Completed"},
{"Card_Status": "Issued"},
{"Card_Status": "In Use"}
]
```

Comment: Your pannel seems to be rendered BEFORE it is filled with datas?

Comment: any error in chrome console?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with local data vs JSON file. You simply aren't setting the predefined store correctly on the list view. You want to add an alias to the store definition, and define the store as an object with *type* of your store alias (minus the prefix). Here is a fiddle:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2bh
(Look specifically at Line #3, and #45)

I would recommend always creating stores via alias like this, it easier allows for management and destruction, and each store created will always be a new instance. Creating stores ahead of time (for example, via Ext.create) and then assigning them to components introduces a huge risk of tying the same store to 2+ dataviews inadvertently.